# Using jQuery to count dynamic <li> elements by class using event handler

Tags: jquery, html, class, event-handling, counting

I'm trying to use jQuery to count *ul li* elements with a certain class. The class is being toggled on and off by another jQuery script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$(".checkbox1").click(function(){
    $("li.tom").toggleClass( "hider" );
});
});
```

I understand that this means that I need to add an event handler to listen for changes in the *ul*:

```
 $('.cartlist').on('click', 'li.hider', function () {

    var total=$('.cartlist > li.hider').length;
        $('.totalCount').html('$' +total * 999); 
    }); });
```

The script I have written half works, in the sense that the .on() handler I am using successfully counts the class *hider*, but only when the *li* items are clicked. No doubt this is because I am using .on('click'). I've read the jQuery docs for .on() and, from what I understand, I should be able to use other DOM hooks like 'load', 'scroll' etc. However, when I replace .on('click') with .on('load') or .on('change'), nothing happens. Also, unchecking the checkboxes doesn't change the total, probably because the handler is tied to the *ul* and doesn't care about the checkboxes...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zC5dS/6/)

I am new here and new to jQuery so please forgive the obvious gaps in my knowledge. Thanks in anticipation for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were observing the **UL** and not the **inputs**:

```
$('.cartlist').on('click', 'li.hider', function () {...
```

If you instead observe the inputs, your method works:

```
$('form').on('click', 'input', function () {
```

Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/C8nCf/

Answer (score 0):

Heres a method for counting elements that contain a specific class.

> > http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/2GZMY/ << JSfiddle

```
// Gets the number of elements with class yourClass
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var numItems = $('.thisClass').length;
    $('.howmany').html("counted: "+numItems);
});
```